# Testing Github Hosted Source With Different PHP Versions

Tags: php

I have few project source hosted with **github**.

what i need is when i commit a new source. it should automatically tests the latest source with different php versions.

My github source : https://github.com/technofreaky/woocomerce-quick-donation

Where there is a issue with php version https://github.com/technofreaky/woocomerce-quick-donation/blob/master/includes/admin/class-admin-functions.php#L137

i came to know about it by a user issue report. but i need to know this via automated testing

i tried **github** interrogations  like **codeship**. but i can't find a way

Comment: Have you tried **github** integration with Travis CI? It's free and works pretty fine.

Comment: @user2655603 ok but i dont know how to configure it

Comment: They have fine documentation as well - http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/ (general) and http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/ (php specific). It's full and detailed. Please check it out and ask there'll be any unexpected problems.

Comment: StackOverflow is a question-answer service. Please **try** to solve the issue by yourself first and ask about **particular** problems, if any.